# Context object does not retrieve the changes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application in which I use Entity Framework for data access. I have a data service class in which I query and retrieve some collections from my database

Here is my code :

```
class ProductDataService:IProductDataService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Context object of Entity Framework model
    /// </summary>
    private R_MaizeEntities Context { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public ProductDataService()
    {
        Context = new R_MaizeEntities();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TblProduct> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var q = from p in Context.TblProducts
                 where p.IsDel == false
                 select p;

        return q.AsEnumerable();

        // This code working fine
        //using(var context=new R_MaizeEntities())
        //{
        //    var q = from p in context.TblProducts
        //            where p.IsDel == false
        //            select p;

        //    return new ObservableCollection<TblProduct>(q);
        //}
    }
}
```

Here is my view model :

```
public class ProductViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    //Constructor
    Public ProductViewModel()
    {
       LoadProductCollection();
    }

    private IProductDataService _dataService;
    public IProductDataService DataService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dataService == null)
            {
                if (IsInDesignMode)
                {
                    _dataService = new ProductDataServiceMock();
                }
                else
                {
                    _dataService = new ProductDataService();
                }
            }
            return _dataService;
        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<TblProduct> _productRecords;
    public ObservableCollection<TblProduct> ProductRecords
    {
        get { return _productRecords; }
        set
        {
            _productRecords = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProductRecords");
        }
    }

    private void LoadProductCollection()
    {
        var q = DataService.GetAllProducts();
        this.ProductRecords = new ObservableCollection<TblProduct>(q);
    }
}
```

My problem: when I updated my existing `product` object and I call the `LoadProductCollection` method to refresh my `ProductRecord` collection (which I bind to a ListView in my view), the collection won't get updated the changes I made, but the database got updated the changes.

On my `ProductDataService` I declare context as a property and initialized it in the constructor, on `GetAllProducts` method I used that context property object to retrieve my collection, this won't get my changes back, instead if I use a context inside the `Using` statement (in the code I commented out) I got the changed collection.

Why my former approach won't retrieve the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visible difference is that, in your former approach you are using the same data context object which you created via constructor every time you call the method.

And in approach which you have commented out, you are creating a new object of the context in using statement every time you call the GetAllProductsMethod(). Hope it helps.

Comment: so whats the best approach to retrieve and save object(s) ,create new context object every time when data access arise ?

Comment: @Angel, it depends on need of your application, because creating new context would have some overhead, and maintaining one context would have some memory overhead. This may help you : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx